# Merging columns and only keeping the dummy variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to merge the columns in this dataset into one columns thereby keeping 1 and 0. What would be the code to do the trick here? I could not find an appropriate code on the dplyr cheat sheet.

Thank you!

```
df = structure(list(cntry = c("BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", "BE", 
"BE", "BE", "BE", "BE"), prtvtcbeR = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 
1, NA, NA, 0), prtvtcczR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    prtvtcdkR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), prtvtdeeR = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), prtvtcfiR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), prtvtcfrR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), prtvdde2R = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtaisR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtaieR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtbilR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtbitR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvalt3R = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtenlR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtanoR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtcplR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtbptR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtdsiR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtbseR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtdchR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtgbR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), prtvtcbgR = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), prtvtacyR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), prtvtcesR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), prtvtcskR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), prtvtdhuR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), ID = 1:10), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hello @Marta, could you help us showing the expected result? I mean, as a structure, just the first rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I was thinking something using `paste` or `unite` or `collapse`, but if there's only one non-NA value per prtv... column, you might be able to do it using `pivot_longer` with `values_drop_na = TRUE`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = prtvtcbeR:prtvtdhuR, names_to = 'prtv', values_to = 'dummy', values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

This will convert the data to long format while removing all NA values so you only end up with 1 row per row in the original df (actually sometimes zero rows if there are no non-NA values in the row):

If you then want to remove the 'prtv' column so you're just left with the country, ID and dummy variable columns, you can just drop it:

```
 df %>% pivot_longer(cols = prtvtcbeR:prtvtdhuR, names_to = 'prtv', values_to = 'dummy', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% select(-prtv)
```

---

Edit: a modified solution that lets you keep the NAs from the relevant country. This assumes that the column names prtvtcXXR always follow that format where XX is the code for the country.

```
df %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = prtvtcbeR:prtvtdhuR, names_to = 'prtv', values_to = 'dummy', values_drop_na = F) %>% 
separate(col = prtv, sep = c(6,8), into = c('drop1', 'Country', 'drop2')) %>% 
mutate(Country = toupper(Country)) %>% 
select(-c(drop1, drop2)) %>%
filter(Country == cntry)
```

Explanation:

- convert to long format so that all of those prtv columns are in one column (called 'prtv'). This will show a ton of rows of NAs for each ID.
- separate the prtv column to extract the two-letter country code (the extra bits on either side will be dropped later)
- convert the country code to uppercase to match `cntry`
- drop those extra columns
- filter the df to keep only those cases where cntry and Country match

That should leave you with one output row per input row.

Comment: Once, again thank you! I have not thought about using tidyverse!

Comment: Maybe another question, how would I modify this to keep the NA values?

Comment: No problem. Just set `values_drop_na = FALSE` to keep NAs (although that's the default so technically you don't need to.)

Comment: Note that will keep all the NA values though, and maybe you only want the NA values for the relevant prtv column to that country?

Comment: I think I have a potential solution for that case, assuming the two letters between prtvtc and R are always the country.

Comment: Hmm.. when I set 'values_drop_na' to false, what happens is I get a data frame with about 1 Mio entries while there should be 44k. Do you know why this happened or how to resolve it?

Comment: I actually would need it with the NA as I have to merge it with my main dataset to run some regressions

Comment: Exactly, this would always be the country code!

Comment: Converting a df with 27 columns and 44k rows to long format will give it 1 million rows, but the filtering step at the end should bring it back down to 44k.

Comment: I see! I get the following error code, though: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `coun`.
x object 'coun' not found
ℹ Input `coun` is `toupper(coun)`.

Comment: That was just me forgetting to change the variable name everywhere. Everywhere it says coun should be Country (have edited it).

Comment: Okay, it worked, I would not have been able to do this - thank you so much!

Comment: No problem :) Converting to long format helps with a surprising amount of things!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231527/discussion-between-marta-and-elle).